# HTML and javascript show multiple div's

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code wich will show/hide respective div's if a value from a dropdown list is selected. The values from the hidden div's will be added to a db.

```js
<script>
document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('change', function ()
{
    var style = number.value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('1tower').style.display = style;
 var style = number.value == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('2tower').style.display = style;
 var style = number.value == 3 ? 'block' : 'none';
 document.getElementById('3tower').style.display = style;
});
</script>
```

```html
<select id="number" name="number_towers">
<option hidden value=""></option>
<option value="1">1 tower</option>
<option value="2">2 towers</option>
<option value="3">3 towers</option>
</select>

<div id="1tower" style="display: none;">
A Tower Value 1: <input type ="text" name = "curent_nominal_sec1"/><br>
B Tower Value 1: <input type ="text" name = "putere_sec1"/><br>
C Tower Value 1: <input type ="text" name = "clasa_precizie_sec1"/></div>

<div id="2tower" style="display: none;">
A Tower Value 2: <input type ="text" name = "curent_nominal_sec2"/><br>
B Tower Value 2: <input type ="text" name = "putere_sec2"/><br>
C Tower Value 2: <input type ="text" name = "clasa_precizie_sec2"/></div>

<div id="3tower" style="display: none;">
A Tower Value 3: <input type ="text" name = "curent_nominal_sec3"/><br>
B Tower Value 3: <input type ="text" name = "putere_sec3"/><br>
C Tower Value 3: <input type ="text" name = "clasa_precizie_sec3"/></div>
```

Is there a way to display div's combinated ?
Example: If I select 2 towers, then display div 1 and 2.
If I select 3 towers, then display div 1,2 and 3.

Any help will be apreciated

Comment: change condition from `==` to `>=`

Comment: didn't think about that. Worked :D Thank you

Comment: 1) You may want to reduce the duplication of document.getElementById and create a function that will take the `id` name and `style` parameters.  2) You can also change the datatype of number.value by putting `+` before it to force parseInt. 3) You can then use `===` instead of `==` to get it make the code working as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to each tower and fetch them in javascript. Then you get the selected number from the dropdown. We'll need that next for the amount of loops. It loops through all towers and checks if `i` is still lower than the `number` selected. If yes, it changes to `block`, else to `none`. You can add as many towers as you want with this code:

```js
var towers = document.getElementsByClassName('tower');
document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var number = this.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < towers.length; i++) {
    towers[i].style.display = i < number ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="number" name="number_towers">
  <option hidden value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1 tower</option>
  <option value="2">2 towers</option>
  <option value="3">3 towers</option>
</select>

<div id="1tower" class="tower" style="display: none;">
  A Tower Value 1:
  <input type="text" name="curent_nominal_sec1" />
  <br>B Tower Value 1:
  <input type="text" name="putere_sec1" />
  <br>C Tower Value 1:
  <input type="text" name="clasa_precizie_sec1" />
</div>

<div id="2tower" class="tower" style="display: none;">
  A Tower Value 2:
  <input type="text" name="curent_nominal_sec2" />
  <br>B Tower Value 2:
  <input type="text" name="putere_sec2" />
  <br>C Tower Value 2:
  <input type="text" name="clasa_precizie_sec2" />
</div>

<div id="3tower" class="tower" style="display: none;">
  A Tower Value 3:
  <input type="text" name="curent_nominal_sec3" />
  <br>B Tower Value 3:
  <input type="text" name="putere_sec3" />
  <br>C Tower Value 3:
  <input type="text" name="clasa_precizie_sec3" />
</div>
```

If you want to add more towers, the only thing you need to do is edit the HTML dropdown with an extra option and a div with the form for an extra tower.

Comment: No problem, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

change condition from `==` to `>=`

```
<script>
document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('change', function ()
{
    var style = number.value >= 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('1tower').style.display = style;
    var style = number.value >= 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('2tower').style.display = style;
    var style = number.value >= 3 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('3tower').style.display = style;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('change', function ()
{
var value = number.value;
document.getElementById('1tower').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('2tower').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('3tower').style.display = 'none';

for (var i = value; i > 0; i--) { 
    document.getElementById(i+'tower').style.display = 'block';
 }
});
</script>
```